# Using bytes to save object data from table to database in java

Tags: java, sql, user-interface, jdbc

After some research it seems that I should be modifying my Object into bytes before sending. As my code is rather extensive i will give it in demonstrative pieces. I have the problem that nothing happens on successful completion of the program.

SAVE and SET variables are named in the following manner within the private void

```
int count = jTable1.getRowCount();

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
//SET0       
        SET0 = new Object[1][count];
        SET0[0][i] = txt.getText();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baosSET0 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oosSET0 = new ObjectOutputStream(baosSET0);
        oosSET0.writeObject(SET0.toString());
        byte[] SET0asBytes = baosSET0.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream baisSET0 = new ByteArrayInputStream(SET0asBytes);
```

AND

```
      SAVE = new Object[1][count];  
      SAVE[0][i] = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i,0);
      ByteArrayOutputStream baosSAVE = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oosSAVE = new ObjectOutputStream(baosSAVE);
        oosSAVE.writeObject(SAVE.toString());
        byte[] SAVEasBytes = baosSAVE.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream baisSAVE = new ByteArrayInputStream(SAVEasBytes);
```

Which leads into my SQL query:

```
 String sqla1 = "INSERT INTO MIT(MTY_KOD,MTY_TYY,MTY_ALU,MTY_PAR1,MTY_PAR2,MTY_TOL,MTY_KAN,MTY_DATE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

 try{
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqla1);

   pst.setBinaryStream(1, baisSET0 , SET0asBytes.length);
   pst.setBinaryStream(2, baisSET2, SET2asBytes.length);
   pst.setBinaryStream(3, baisSET1, SET1asBytes.length);
   pst.setBinaryStream(4, baisSAVE, SAVEasBytes.length);
   pst.setBinaryStream(5, baisSAVE3, SAVE3asBytes.length);
   pst.setBinaryStream(6, baisSAVE5, SAVE5asBytes.length);
   pst.setBinaryStream(7, baisSET3, SET3asBytes.length);
   pst.setBinaryStream(8, baisSET2, SET2asBytes.length);

   pst.executeUpdate();}
 catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Event is triggered from:

```
if(txt.getText().isEmpty()){
    }else{ 
        try{
    INSERT();}
        catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

The error i get is:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The stream value is not the specified length. The specified length was 35, the actual length is 0.
```

Can anyone direct me on how to fix this error... or a different method of saving the information? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to close your `ObjectOutputStream`.

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeInt(12345);
oos.writeObject("Today");
oos.writeObject(new Date());
oos.close();   // <-- my emphasis!
```

Comment: thank you for reading... yes its true i forgot to add the close for the problems but for some reason the same issue persists after fixing the issue... i added
            oosSET.writeObject(SET.toString());
            oosSET.close();

Comment: also tried to change oosSET.writeObject(SET) ... so without the toString resulting in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The stream value is not the specified length. The specified length was 111, the actual length is 0.